# Issue with importing of variable

Tags: python

please help me to find the solution of my issue. 
I have a file main.py

```
def arguments_reader():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
    parser.add_argument('--bindhost', dest='host', default='localhost',
                        help='Hostname to bind (default:localhost)')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.host

if __name__ == "__main__":
    action = arguments_reader()
....
```

and second one test.py

```
class TEST(object):

    def __init__(*args):
        print(host)
```

How i can get variable host from first file?
P.S. I'm running main.py
P.S.S. I can't run TEST class in main.py (it's running by other file) so I can't post it like argument, only import in test.py, main.py file

Thanks

Comment: So what is stopping you from importing it? You need to explicitly define your arguments in `__init__()`, e.g. `def __init__(self, host)`. Then you can construct an instance in `main.py`, e.g. `t = TEST(action)`

Comment: Import the `argument_reader` function  from `main.py`, call the function and assign the result to some variable. Then pass the variable name into the constructor for `TEST`. Or do what @AChampion said if you want to import `TEST` into `main.py`.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Show all the code necessary to illustrate what you are doing. Anyone should be able to copy and paste your code then run it and get the exact same results which you are asking about.

Comment: Use global [var_name] inside , maybe!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass host as an argument to constructor of TEST class and create it instance once you are done with parsing of arguments .. You files should like this

main.py

```
from test import TEST
import argparse

.....

def arguments_reader():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
    parser.add_argument('--bindhost', dest='host', default='localhost',
                    help='Hostname to bind (default:localhost)')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.host

if __name__ == "__main__":
    action = arguments_reader()
    test = TEST(action) 
.....
```

ans test.py

```
class TEST(object):

    def __init__(self, host):
        print(host)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import `main.py`:

```
import main

class TEST(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.host = main.arguments_reader()
```

One thing to be careful about is that if you are using `unittest`, `UnitTest.main()` consumes the command-line arguments.